# Inside an id div find all the checkbox and check and hide other unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i am trying to learn and create a jquery which `$("#answer")` and find all the checkbox inside and check. As an example if checkbox inside `#a1` is checked other div (a2,a3,a4) is hidden or other message come out. if i uncheck the `#a1` all the div will come out again.
Please enlighten me on the code.

```
  <div id="answer">
    <div id="a1">A.<input type="checkbox" name="a1" onclick="cbox()" ></input></div>
    <div id="a2">B. <input type="checkbox" name="a2"onclick="cbox()"></input></div>
    <div id="a3">C. <input type="checkbox" name="a3"onclick="cbox()"></input></div>
    <div id="a4">D. <input type="checkbox" name="a4"onclick="cbox()"></input></div>
                        </div>


function cbox() {
  if (this checkbox is checked)  { 
    target other div inside (#answer) and add .hide()
  }
}
```

2)Is there anyway to add a trigger where i don't need to use onlick="cbox" ?

tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use **[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** instead of inline javascript `onclick`.

However, you should use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event for `input` elements instead of click:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div').toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKEZY/1/)**

Comment: can u help me to touch up toggle the check box ? i can only check but can't uncheck it now :(

Comment: Did you see my demo? The checkbox can be checked and unchecked.

Comment: Yup , but i change abit to target the whole div to trigger the checkbox

$("#answer > div").click(function(){

 var cbox =  $(this).find("input:checkbox")
     cbox.attr("checked",true);
     $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle(!this.checked); 
    });

Comment: btw , how do i detect which checkbox i checked ?

Comment: is this  $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", !status); the one checking it ?

Comment: I have figure out this     
$("#answer").find("input:checkbox:checked").val();       , but i can't figure out how to detect if no checkbox was checked

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parent('div').siblings('div').toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/ZhSXt/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#answer input").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#answer input").not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
        })
    } else {
        $("#answer input").not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).parent().css("display", "block");
        })
    }
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/9eUy3/)